# php preg_match_all simple regex returns empty values

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract a predefined set of hashtags from a blob of text, then extract what number follows right after it if any. Eg. I'd need to extract 30 from "Test string with #other30 hashtag". I assumed preg_match_all would be the right choice.

Some test code:

```
$hashtag = '#other';
$string  = 'Test string with #other30 hashtag';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/' . $hashtag . '\d*/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #other30
        )
)
```

Perfect... Works as expected. Now to extract the number:

```
$string = $matches[0][0]; // #other30
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/\d*/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
            [2] =>
            [3] =>
            [4] =>
            [5] =>
            [6] => 30
            [7] =>
        )
)
```

What? Looks like it's trying to match every character?

I'm aware of some preg_match_all related answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280335/how-to-clear-preg-match-all-from-empty-array-values), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816378/getting-empty-array-results-using-preg-match-all-for-values-that-dont-match)), but they all use a parenthesized subpattern. According to documentation - it is optional.

What am I missing? How do I simply get all matches into an array that match such a basic regex like /\d*/ There doesn't seem to be a more appropriate function in php for that.

I never thought I'd be scratching my head with such a basic thing in PHP. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
preg_match_all('/\d*/', $string, $matches);
```

with:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches);
```

Replace `*` with `+`

Because

> `*` Match zero or more times.
>
> `+` Match one or more times.

Comment: Such a silly mistake... * matches **zero** or more of the preceding element... It tries to match zero digits. Duh

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capturing group:

```
preg_match_all('/' . $hashtag . '(\d*)/', $string, $matches); 
echo $matches[1][0] . "\n";
//=> 30
```

Here `(\d*)` will capture the number after `$hashtag`.

Comment: Even better! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also see, that you can [reset after a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640447/regexps-variable-length-lookbehind-assertion-alternatives/11640500#11640500) to get part of a match by using `\K`. And of course need to use `\d+` instead of `\d*` to match one or more digits. Else there would be matches in gaps in between the characters [where ***zero*** or more digits matches](https://regex101.com/r/pF3fH1/1).

[image]

So your code can be reduced to

```
$hashtag = '#other';
$string  = 'Test string with #other30 #other31 hashtag';
preg_match_all('/' . $hashtag . '\K\d+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the [demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/463635) and consider using [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for `$hashtag`.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of the \K flag. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/0tcp-13x6)

```
<?php

    $hashtag = '#other';
    $string  = 'Test string with #other30 hashtag';
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all('/' . $hashtag . '\d*/', $string, $matches);
    $string = preg_match_all('#\d+#', $matches[0][0], $m);
    echo $m[0][0];

?>
```